# Geopandas error: GeocoderNotFound: Unknown geocoder 'geocodefarm'

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm following a tutorial on geocoding using geopandas. This is my code:

```
import geopandas

place = "Sankt Gallen"
geopandas.tools.geocode(place).explore()
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
GeocoderNotFound: Unknown geocoder 'geocodefarm'; options are: dict_keys(['algolia', 'arcgis', 'azure', 'baidu', 'baiduv3', 'banfrance', 'bing', 'databc', 'geocodeearth', 'geocodio', 'geonames', 'google', 'googlev3', 'geolake', 'here', 'herev7', 'ignfrance', 'mapbox', 'mapquest', 'maptiler', 'nominatim', 'opencage', 'openmapquest', 'pickpoint', 'pelias', 'photon', 'liveaddress', 'tomtom', 'what3words', 'what3wordsv3', 'yandex'])
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Did the tutorial you are following have you change the provider somewhere along the way? I would just follow the [GeoPandas Documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/geocoding.html) but I generally use arcgis as I find it to be more accurate - `geopandas.tools.geocode(place, provider='arcgis').explore()`

Comment: thanks @It_is_Chris - I tried that, but then I get an error: `AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'explore'`. I'll follow the tutorial on the official documentation, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an outdated version of the `geopandas` package installed, have you tried updating?

Alternatively, you may wish to try using the `provider` keyword argument in the geocode method with one of the options provided in the error message.

`geopandas.tools.geocode(place, provider='your_chosen_option').explore()`

Comment: Thanks @JoshC - looks like I'll need an API key for most of those options. Should be able to figure it out, thank you!

Comment: No worries, hope you can get it working!